# Java - How To Set An Image Path Without Using The C:\\ Direcory

Tags: java, image, io, icons

I created a java app and I put some images in it and even gave it an image icon as the desktop image, but when i made it a jar file, and put it on another pc, all images were gone. This is the image path :

```
 File imageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Favour's Computer\\workspace\\Physics Calculator\\src\\res\\icon.jpg");
```

I checked it online and i found out that the problem is that i got the file through the C:\\ directory, they said the image file should look like this :

```
 File imageFile = new File("res/icon.jpg");
```

I tried this but it didnt work, I kept getting an error message like : file not found

This is my full code :

```
BufferedImage image = null;
try {
File imageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Favour's Computer\\workspace\\Physics Calculator\\src\\res\\icon.jpg");
        image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setIconImage(image);
```

Please, i have been trying to solve this for weeks, do anyone know how i can solve this, please if you do, please help

Comment: Is is a static java project or a web project?

Comment: it is a static java app

Comment: @user3526881 not **static java app** it's a **core java app** my friend

Comment: And the image is inside src/res/icon.jpg of your project?

Comment: Thank You Very Much user3526881, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The images should not be loaded from the file system, but should be bundled into the app, inside your jar.

If you put the image `foo.png` inside the jar, under the package `com.bar.resources` for example, you simply need to use

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/bar/resources/foo.png")
```

to load the image as an input stream.

That will use the class loader to load the image. So, during development, if you're using a standard IDE project, you just need to put the image file in the appropriate package in your source directory: the IDE will "compile" the file by copying it to the same directory as the generated .class files. 
If you're using a standard Maven/Gradle project, then it needs to be put in the appropriate package under `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Thank you for helping, your code works, it seems that the problem was instead of using the src folder, i put it in a local folder inside the src folder, but i am curious, what is the difference between your code and this : File file = new File("src/res/icon.png).

Comment: It's quite simple. Your end user doesn't have any image file on his/her disk. All he/she has is your jar file. `ImageIO.read(File)` reads an image from a file. So it can't work, since the end user doesn't have your image on his/her disk. My code reads the image using the class loader. It thus reads a *resource* from the classpath, which is, in your case, the jar file, which should contain the image. Read the javadoc from the methods and classes you use. They explain what they do.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you dont have res folder in your project, first of create a folder  a "res" by Right Clicking on project and place the image icon.jpg image in that "res". and

```
use : `File imageFile = new File("res/icon.jpg");`// To retrieve image to your project.
```

You cannot retrieve the image from your local system, because it is not attached with your projects workspace.

Answer (score -1):

There are two options....

1)Either make `res` a "source folder" . You will know this if you are using Eclipse.
Then you can use like

```
ImageIO.read(new File("res/icon.jpg"));
```

2) If res is a normal folder, you will have to use. In this case res will be considered as a package

```
ImageIO.read(new File("src/res/icon.jpg"));
```

Comment: This code loads the image from a location relative to the current directory. Whether the res file is a "source" project or not doesn't change anything. The current directory is the directory from which the java command is launched. And the end user doesn't have any "project" and any "source" folder. All it has is an application, as a jar file.

Comment: Yes that is right. I was being too narrow, sorry about that. I think option 2 could be used, or the classpath.getResource.... method

Comment: Option 2 makes as less sense as option 1. It loads a *file* (which doesn't exist on the end user machine).

Comment: res being a package inside source, should be part of the jar file. Why are you saying it doesn't exist in end user machine?

Comment: It exists as a resource inside the jar file. It doesn't exist as a file on the end user file system. So, trying to read it with `ImageIO.read(new File("src/res/icon.jpg"))` can't possibly work, since that will load a *file* named icon.jpg, under the directory `res`, under the directory `src`, under the current directory. The end user doesn't have such an src directory on its file system. And you don't know what his current directory is, because he can choose to execute the application from wherever he wants.